# How do i fix this error in next js TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'className')

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, next.js

I am working on a next js project , copied some coe on code pen , it is used for a product design of an e commerce website . However i am having this problem.
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'className'). What is an equalvalent of
getElementsByClassName or how can i override this eror
here is a glimse of the code

```
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("sliderBlock_items");
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("sliderBlock_items__itemPhoto");
    var next = document.getElementsByClassName("sliderBlock_controls__arrowForward")[0];
    var previous = document.getElementsByClassName("sliderBlock_controls__arrowBackward")[0];
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("sliderBlock_positionControls")[0];
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`document.querySelector(".your_class_name").value`
`querySelector()` can be used to select elements on a page, just pass in a CSS like selector...

Cannot set value of undefined would mean that you are trying to select `HTML` elements that are not on the page. This could mean your code gets run before the components get rendered

Share your full code, or add that code inside a `useEffect()`